# Removing terminal special character `^@`

Tags: special-characters, trim

when I `less` a file, it looks like this.

```
^@00002201-271f-43b9-81a7-000b0a31abe5
^@00004695-2281-44df-b18d-bd68b63fced4
^@00009273-3a0f-4c2e-b708-805e02147f55
^@0000a0e6-3889-43f2-9635-63e114c38f29
^@0000a386-cf2f-4459-bd63-e83fb144013c
```

The problem is `^@`.
When `cat` this file, that character is not seen.

What is that character? And How can I trim that (in `C` or `awk` whatever)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`^@` represents the NULL (0x00) byte. (The `^x` is shorthand for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>*x*</kbd>, which on terminals would clear the two highest bits of the pressed key; so while `A` is `0x41 [0100'0001]`, Ctrl+A would input `0x01 [0000'0001]`, and so on.)

To remove it, pipe through `sed 's/^\x00//'`, or `sed 's/\x00//g'` if it occurs in other places.

However, NULL is usually simply ignored. If the first character gets trimmed, then you probably have something *more* than that in the file. Consider looking at its hexdump, e.g. with `xxd`, `hexdump -C`, `cat -v`, or `sed -n l`.